how to disable bootstrap DataTables horizontal scroll
I have this horizontal bar that is completely unfunctional, and it is looking very bad:

I was wondering if I could delete it but only using the js in "_MyLayout" file:
$('.table').DataTable({
    pageLength: 50,
    pagingType: "full_numbers",
    scrollY: '300px',
    scrollCollapse: true
});

Also, if it is necessary to use the "site.css" file I have an issue with using it, as I do any changes and it does not work. I made sure that the site.css is loaded after style.min.css:
<link href="~/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />

But whenever I try adding anything to this file, nothing is responsive apart from this font size inside of the "@media" bracket:
html {
    font-size: 14px;
}

**@media** (min-width: 768px) {
    html {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

body {
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}


Maybe I am not understanding, but if you wish to remove horizontal scrolling, even if it is present, why not .table{overflow-x:hidden !important}? This removes scrolling on the horizontal axis

This question is similar to: Problems with Datatables and unwanted Horizontal scrollbar. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
